# mx record with IPv6 AAAA host

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, ipv6, hmailserver

I need to setup a mail server or mx record with a IPv6 address

I have written a AAAA record which is working fine (pings, ports) [here](http://host.nvoids.com)

I have setup hmailserver and checked all ports(587, 143) with portchecker.co which are again working fine

I have setup a mx record with host and pointed it to host.nvoids.com
but that is not working

My Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file looks like -

```
2405:201:4000:60f3:49c9:9748:bc54:11c5  host.nvoids.com     host
fe80::49c9:9748:bc54:11c5%11        host.nvoids.com     host
```

when i telnet port 25 it does not connect

I have no clue where things are wrong now

**EDIT**
I edited hmail server iP ranges and priority

:: to ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
[image]

I'm able to receive emails but still not able to send now

Thunderbird or Outlook doesn't complain anything during send but external mailboxes do not receive emails.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve: email reception on IPv6 or email delivery to external hosts, be it IPv4 or IPv6 and what exactly is working and what not. Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

host.nvoids.com doesn't have AAAA record so please check and make sure that have already added AAAA record on dns server for host.nvoids.com